# datatables jquery pedidos ao servidor com parameteros

Tags: jquery

tenho um form de pesquisa onde coloco o NIF para fazer uma procura.

Pertendo usar o datatables para preencher a informação que é retornada pelo echo json .

tenho este codigo no javascript o data.id envia o id para o php .

```
function getfichauser() {
    $('#ficha').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: "../Logica/user/getficha.php",
            "type": "GET",
            "data": function (data) {
                 data.id = $('#nif').val();
            },
        },
            "columns": [{
            "data": "NOME"
        }, {
            "data": "MORADA"
        }, {
            "data": "LOCALIDADE"
        }]
    });
};
```

agora tenho este codigo em php recebo o NIF por parametero
 $nif = $_GET["nif"];

```
        $query="SELECT * from USER where NIF=:NIF";
   $db = new ligacao();
    $conn = $db->open();
    $stmt= $conn->prepare($query); 
     $stmt->bindParam(':NIF', $nif, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $table = array();
    $rows = array();


        foreach ($result as $row) {
        $rows[]=$row;           
  }


   echo "{ \"data\":".json_encode($rows). "}";
```

Comment: Olá, o teu retorno `JSON` deve ser algo parecido com isto `{ "data": [ {"NOME" : "Primeiro Nome", "MORDA": "Primeira Morada", "LOCALIDADE": "Primeira Localidade"} ] }`, ou seja, deves colocar o prefixo `data` no teu conjunto de valores. Assim: `echo "{ \"data\":".json_encode($rows). "}"`. Experimenta isto e diz o que retornou.

Comment: sim gerou-me isso, o problema deve estar na forma como estou a chamar o código do php do lado do java script. a variavel esta bem?. é que se fizer no form action e chamar o ficheiro  php apos o submit ele gera bem o json faz bem o output.

Comment: Olha para ser sincero, eu também não estou acostumado a trabalhar com plugins, principalmente este que até hoje era-me estranho, porém fiz testes e tive sucesso em todos, só que de forma diferente. É possível editares a pergunta e colocares o script todo ? Talvez assim consiga entender melhor a ideia de como queres passar o valor.

Comment: alguma ajuda...

Comment: Olha, parece que o `plugin` faz tudo internamente, o `exemplo` mais objetivo que consegui encontrar no diretório deles foi este [aqui](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysqli), porém não está a funcionar, no caso teria de se reescrever o `script` todo numa remota possibilidade de conseguir coloca-lo em funcionamento.

Comment: De momento uma das soluções mais fáceis que me vem em mente, é retornar os valores todos no `script`, porque eu mesmo já tentei via `GET` pelo ajax, e o `dataTable` não aceita ser reinicializado. Mais detalhes são sempre bem vindos, podes sempre tentar explicar melhor o que queres, caso eu esteja em erro com a tua explicação e as minhas sugestões.

Comment: pois eu fiz a querie e returnei do resultado no php e chamei a funçao apos fazer o sumbit e assim o datatables ja come...mas nao é assim que pertendo.quero é fazer o pedido por ajax ao servidor

Comment: Foi exatamente isto que acabei de dizer :/, o `plugin` barra algumas funcionalidades e algumas opções, pelo `PHP`.

Comment: mas acho que ja la estou a chegar...a fazer o pedido...vou testar passar o parametero a ver se funca

Comment: nao da tentei passar o id sacando apos submit mas manda-me um id diferente do que era suposto lol

Comment: Amigo, eu já tenho a resposta que procuras, mas estou a reescrever para as `Prepared Statments` o que está a ser um bocado trabalhoso. Tem algum problema se eu responder com o `MySQLi` normal ?

Comment: boas estou a usar o sql server e estou a usar o PDO

Comment: mas para abrir o datatables tem de ser assim xD senao ele não abre... $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: vi este exemplo mas tbm nao deu https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i41WoX-B5f4

Comment: Há um erro aqui no script que reescrevi, estou a tentar corrigir, depois respondo à pergunta, mas usarei `MySQLi` depois podes tentar adaptar.

Answer (score 1):

Este exemplo aqui utiliza a `caixa de busca` do próprio `DataTable` para realizar buscas no banco de dados.

## HTML - Cliente

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>DataTables - Exemplo com MySQLi &plus; PHP</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="">
            <h1 style="text-align:center; font-family: Arial; font-weight:300;">DataTables - Exemplo com MySQLi &plus; PHP </h1>
            <section>
                <table id="tabela" class="display" cellspacing="0" with="90%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jogo</td>
                            <td>Console</td>
                            <td>Preço</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jogo</td>
                            <td>Console</td>
                            <td>Preço</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>    
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#tabela').DataTable({
                            "processing": true,
                            "serverSide": true,
                            "ajax": "Data.php"
                        });
                    } );

                </script>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Agora, segue o script `PHP` que retorna os valores do banco de dados no formato `JSON`.

## PHP - Servidor

```
<?php
// Criado por Parvez; Ou seja qual for o nome real dele
// Exemplo tirado orignalmente de: http://phpflow.com/php/datatable-pagination-sorting-and-search-server-side-phpmysql-using-ajax/
// Modificado por mim

//Conexao
// - example é o nome do banco de dados que usei
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "example");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("Erro:".mysqli_connect_error()."(.". mysqli_connect_errno() .".)"); 
}
//var_dump($db);
//------------------------

//Variaveis Compostas
$params = $colunas = $totalConsultas = $dados = array();
//Variaveis Simples
$where = $sql_total = $sql = "";
//Variaveis HTTP
$params = $_GET;
//Indexes
$colunas = array(0 => 'nome', 1 => 'console', 2 => 'preco');

//Valor de  Busca existe ?
if(!empty($params['search']) && $params['search']['value'] !== ""){
    $where = "WHERE ";
$where .= "( nome LIKE '%{$params['search']['value']}%' ";
    $where .= "OR console LIKE '%{$params['search']['value']}%' )"; 
}

//Total de Resultados Sem Valor de Busca
$SQL = "SELECT nome, console, preco FROM jogos ";
$sql_total .= $SQL;
$sql .= $SQL;

//Concatenar termo de busca se o valor existir
if(isset($where) && $where !== ""){
    $sql_total .= $where;
    $sql .= $where; 
}

//Ordenar e definir os LIMITES/OFFSETS
$sql .= "ORDER BY {$colunas[$params['order'][0]['column']]} {$params['order'][0]['dir']} LIMIT {$params['start']}, {$params['length']}";

//Obter o numero geral de consulta existentes para calcular o numero de páginas
$query_total = mysqli_query($db, $sql_total) or die("Erro: Não foi possivel contar os resultados - ". mysqli_connect_error());
$totalConsultas = mysqli_num_rows($query_total);

//Obter o conjunto de consultas existentes
$query_sql = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("Erro: Nenhum resultado encontrado - ". mysqli_connect_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query_sql)){
    $dados[] = $row;    
}

$formato_json = array(
        "draw"           => intval($params["draw"]), 
        "recordsTotal"   => intval($totalConsultas), 
        "recordsFiltered"=> intval($totalConsultas), 
        "data"           => $dados);

echo json_encode($formato_json);

?>
```

## Tabela SQL

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `jogos`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jogos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `console` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `preco` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nome` (`nome`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `jogos`
--

INSERT INTO `jogos` (`id`, `nome`, `console`, `preco`) VALUES
(1, 'Resident Evil - Retaliacao', 'XBOX 360', '3000.00'),
(2, 'The Elders Scrolls - Skyrim', 'XBOX 360', '5000.00');
```

## Detalhes:

O `DataTables` trata da requisição no lado do servidor, enviando parâmetros pela `url ($_GET, $_REQUEST)`.

Isto é um exemplo, de quando abres o ficheiro index.html que contém a código `jQuery` que cria o `DataTables`:

> http://localhost/projects/Data.php?draw=1&columns[0][data]=0&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[0][orderable]=true&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[1][data]=1&columns[1][name]=&columns[1][searchable]=true&columns[1][orderable]=true&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][search][regex]=false&columns[2][data]=2&columns[2][name]=&columns[2][searchable]=true&columns[2][orderable]=true&columns[2][search][value]=&columns[2][search][regex]=false&order[0][column]=0&order[0][dir]=asc&start=0&length=10&search[value]=&search[regex]=false&_=1441820166780

O que acontece, é que o plugin `DataTables` envia logo estes parâmetros ao script/endereço no campo `url` da chamada `Ajax`, e sempre que é digitado um valor na `caixa de busca`, ou quando existem mais de `10 resultados` e o usuário clica para ir à próxima página, é feita uma nova requisição e os valores retornados pelo `script` selecionado é modificado consonante a requisição feita.

No caso o `NIF`, seria o campo `nif` no banco de dados.
Para sabermos qual foi o valor do `NIF` digitado na busca do `DataTables`, faríamos algo assim:

> $params = $_GET;
>
> $nif = $params['search']['value'];

E depois na cláusula `WHERE` do `SQL` farias algo assim:

> WHERE nif LIKE '%$nif%'

O que iria retornar apenas colunas com o `NIF` correspondente à busca.

## Exemplo 2:

Reescrevendo a função para algo assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#tabela').DataTable({
                            "processing": true,
                            "serverSide": true,
                            "ajax": {
                                "url": "Data.php",
                                "data": function ( d ) {
                                    d.myKey = "myValue";
                                    // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
                                    // etc
                                }
                            }

                        });
                    } );
```

No ficheiro `Data.php`, se tentares retornar o valor de `$_GET['mykey']`, ou se definires o valor da parte comentada `d.custom = $('#myInput').val();`, e tentares retornar o valor no `PHP` usando `$_GET['custom']`, terás o valor do `input` com `id="myinput"`, ou `myValue` para o caso do `$_GET['mykey']`.

São estas as únicas maneiras de passar dados usando o `DataTable`.

Sendo que podes inverter o processo, priorizando antes a leitura dos campo `input`, e só depois ativar o `DataTable` através de um `CallBack`. Se isto não te puder ajudar amigo, não sei o que mais pode.

## Dica:

Podes ler quais parâmetros foram enviados pelo `DataTables` ativando o `Console Web > Rede` e fazer um `refresh` na página.

No caso do parâmetro personalizado que defini ali em cima `d.mykey` foi-me apresentado algo assim:

```
http://
        127.0.0.1/
        projects/
        Data.php?draw=1
        &columns[0][data]=0
        &columns[0][name]=
        &columns[0][searchable]=true
        &columns[0][orderable]=true
        &columns[0][search][value]=
        &columns[0][search][regex]=false
        &columns[1][data]=1
        &columns[1][name]=
        &columns[1][searchable]=true
        &columns[1][orderable]=true
        &columns[1][search][value]=
        &columns[1][search][regex]=false
        &columns[2][data]=2
        &columns[2][name]=
        &columns[2][searchable]=true
        &columns[2][orderable]=true
        &columns[2][search][value]=
        &columns[2][search][regex]=false
        &order[0][column]=0
        &order[0][dir]=asc
        &start=0
        &length=10
        &search[value]=
        &search[regex]=false
        &myKey=myValue // Aqui, este campo dantes não existia.
        &_=1441908981287
```

Separei os parâmetros para melhor leitura.

Existe um exemplo original do `DataTables`, porém a requisição é bem mais complexa, daí eu ter procurado este exemplo. Espero que isto te ajude, porque a mim também ajudou, conheci este `plugin` dum jeito que nem esperava, mas vê-se que é bom partido.

Comment: OLA mas no teu script nao passas parameteros

Comment: acho que ja resolvi o problema :)   "aaData": data.data, faltava isto xD

Comment: O script passa parâmetros na `URL` pelo `input search`, a tabela é formatada internamente pela saída `JSON` que o `PHP` retorna. Agora que dizes isso, não consigo entender o que realmente queres.

Comment: ola eu tenho um form de pesquisa onde mando por parâmetro os dados do formulário... usei a ferramenta serialize para ir buscar a informação...esse params nunca ouvi falar mas no teu DATA.php não tens de mandar isso por parametero?

Comment: agora estou com outro problema, amanha vou testar a tua solução.... quero meter um loading ao clicar no botão de pesquisar colocar um loading numa div e desaparecer quando tiver os dados do lado do cliente mostra o datatables

Comment: Olha, eu começo a ficar cada vez mais confuso, acerca daquilo que realmente queres, e penso que não te vou poder ajudar a resolver o problema, ou mesmo chegar lá perto, sendo que as tuas explicações não são as mais claras.

Comment: Esta provavelmente terá sido a última `edição` que fiz na minha resposta, sendo que não tenho mais o que explicar nela, até porque acho que está bastante clara, e reuni o máximo de informação possível, espero que faças bom proveito dessa informação, amigo.

Comment: não esta clara...a questão é que o teu exemplo não esta a ir buscar informação as datatables

Comment: vou tentar fazer da tua maneira...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29041/discussion-between-edilson-and-user2964140).

Answer (score 0):

```
php **`**        $rows = array();
    $table =array();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
        $rows[] = $row;
  }
   $table['data'] = $rows;
  echo json_encode($table);
```

**`**

tenho este codigo  js`**

```
    $( "#pesquisa" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
          event.preventDefault();
            var pesquisa = $("#pesquisa").serialize();
     //                var nif= document.getElementById('nif').value;

          $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"../Logica/user/user.php",
                dataType:'json',
                data:pesquisa,

                success: function(data){

                     $('#tomadores').dataTable({
                       "aaData": data.data,
                        "aoColumns": [
                     { "mData": "NUMERO" },
                     { "mData": "MORADA" },
                     { "mData": "LOCALIDADE" },
                      { "mData": "TELEFONE" }
                 ]


                            });

                }
          });

    });
    </script>** `
```

resolvido

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz assim no meu

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": "assets/controle/json.php?op=cliente_data_json",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "nome" },
        { "data": "razaosocial" },
        { "data": "opcoes" }
    ]
}).ajax.reload(null, false);
```

No meu php fiz assim

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['op'])) {
    $op = $_REQUEST['op'];
}

switch ($op) {

    case 'cliente_data_json': {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes");
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                while ($dados = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                    $data['data'][] = array(
                        "id" => "$dados->id",
                        "nome" => "$dados->nome",
                        "razaosocial" => "$dados->razao_social",
                        "opcoes" => "<div class='btn-group btn-group-sm'><button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-info' id='edit_" . $dados->id . "'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Editar</button>&nbsp;<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' id='del_" . $dados->id . "'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Deletar</button></div>"
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }break;

}
```

Comment: E quando quiser da um load na tabela depois que vc incluir um registro só colocar depois da inclusão ajax o comando:

$('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);

Que ele atualizar o dataTable automático sem refresh.

Comment: na url do datatable ajax pode também concatenar ex: "ajax": "assets/controle/json.php?op=cliente_data_json&parametro1=" + parametro1 + "&parametro2=" + parametro2 + "",

Comment: var data = "assets/controle/json.php?op=cliente_data_json" + "&parametro1=" + parametro1 + "&parametro2=" + parametro2; "ajax": data,