# DataTable criar e preencher table dinamicamente com paginação server-side

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Pessoal como posso fazer com que ao submeter um form, uma DataTable seja criada e populada com o resultado do filtro feito no form
e fazer com que o DataTable faça a paginação server-side.

DataTable Version: 1.9.4

A primeira parte de criar o DataTable e popular com o resultado está funcionando assim:

```
var table = $('#exemplo').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true
});

$('#enviar').click(function(event) {
    var formData = $('form[name="form-teste"]').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'consulta.php',
        method: 'GET',
        data: formData + '&action=consulta',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            table.fnClearTable();
        }
    }).done(function(data)
    {
        table.fnAddData(data.data);

    }).fail(function(error)
    {
        console.log('error');
    });

});
```

O JSON está assim:

```
{
    "draw":0,
    "recordsTotal":2,
    "recordsFiltered":2,
    "data":
        [
            [
                "teste 1",
                "3232132",
                "237",
                "123",
                "456",
                "joao",
                "1000.00",
                "300.00",
                "62079786768",
                null
            ],
            [
                "teste 2",
                "33323",
                "237",
                "123",
                "456",
                "joao",
                "1000.00",
                "300.00",
                "62079786768",
                null
            ]
        ]
}
```

Agora a parte da paginação server-side é que não encontro uma solução

Comment: Veja isto - [DataTables Paginação com parâmetros](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85680/datatables-jquery-pedidos-ao-servidor-com-parameteros/86054#86054)

Comment: Não ajudou em nada @Edilson mas valew assim mesmo cara

Comment: É basicamente aquilo que estás à procura. Coloca o código que estás a usar atualmente para a tua consulta.

Comment: Mas isso o meu já faz, estou procurando agora é uma solução para paginação server-side

Comment: Mas a parte da paginação também está lá.

Comment: Olá. Eu também procurei bastante e gostaria de saber como fazer isso.
Contudo, encontrei uma solução excelente no link abaixo.
https://coderexample.com/datatable-scroller-server-side/
Felicidades.